# Retrieve SQL objects instead or rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database. 
Table columns are as follows

```
************Itinerary*********
USERNAME      ITIN

**********Flight Details**********
ITIN    FROM    TO     START_DATE     END_DATE     START_TIME     END_TIME
```

I would like to retrieve into my server with an SQL query to retrieve multiple objects based on the ITN number. Meaning, my ITIN number has a many to one relationship with the rest of the details. (One ITIN can have many flights and one USERNAME can have many ITIN numbers)

My object on my server side should be like follows:

```
String username, int ITIN, List flightDetails
```

I would receive an ITIN for every row I retrieve right now. The one solution I found is to make as many calls to database as there are ITIN numbers for each user. But that results in multiple calls being made. 
 
Other way I thought is to traverse the result set from top to bottom and create a new object for each new ITIN encountered. That results in my looping through all the rows.

Is there a better solution to this problem where I could get one ITIN and USERNAME and multiple rows of flight details so that can be directly inserted into my object?

Comment: What queries are your running?

Comment: select * from Flight_Details where ITIN IN (select ITIN from Itinerary where USERNAME = "XYZ"). <br/>
When I do this, I see all rows with ITIN in each row. But is there a way I could group all Flight_Details with only one ITIN value retrieved? Like an object I mentioned?

Comment: First, add the query to the question (edit your question).  Second, I suggest you use a join and parametrise the ITIN.  Something like `SELECT * FROM itinerary it JOIN flight_details fd ON it.itin = fd.itin` WHERE it.itin='XYZ'`

Answer (score 0):

For one query, you will get back one results. Results are tabular.

Use the ITIN and USERNAME from the first row, and then loop through all rows for the flight details. (I'm not sure what language you are using, so I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader.)

Make sure to a LEFT JOIN if necessary.

Comment: I am doing the same right now but would like a better solution where I could get the data back sort of like an object. Is that possible?

Comment: @user2250885 Not with pure SQL, but you could use a framework to do the ORM mapping for you.

Comment: Yes, you are looking for an ORM. You won't have to put it into objects yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.username,a.itin from Itinerary a join  Flight Details b ON a.itin=b.itin order by a.itin
```